# ORACLE join two table with comma separated ids

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables

Table 1

```
ID     NAME
1      Person1
2      Person2
3      Person3
```

Table 2

```
ID     GROUP_ID
1      1
2      2,3
```

The IDs in all the columns above refer to the same ID (Example - a Department)

My Expected output (by joining both the tables)

```
GROUP_ID     NAME
1            Person1
2,3          Person2,Person3
```

Is there a query with which I can achieve this.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values. Fix your data model and things get a lot easier

Comment: this is going to get ugly -- you have to first split Table 2 to have 3 rows, do the join, them merge the rows again.  It can be done -- but really, do you want to?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. You shouldn't do it, but perhaps you don't have the power to change the world. (If you have a say in it, you should normalize your table design - in your case, both the input and the output fail the first normal form).

Answering more as good practice for myself...  This solution guarantees that the names will be listed in the same order as the id's. It is not the most efficient, and it doesn't deal with id's in the list that are not found in the first table (it simply discards them instead of leaving a marker of some sort).

```
with
     table_1 ( id, name ) as (
       select 1, 'Person1' from dual union all
       select 2, 'Person2' from dual union all
       select 3, 'Person3' from dual
     ),
     table_2 ( id, group_id ) as (
       select 1, '1' from dual union all
       select 2, '2,3' from dual
     ),
     prep ( id, lvl, token ) as (
       select id, level, regexp_substr(group_id, '[^,]', 1, level)
       from   table_2
       connect by level <= regexp_count(group_id, ',') + 1
              and prior id = id
              and prior sys_guid() is not null
     )
select p.id, listagg(t1.name, ',') within group (order by p.lvl) as group_names
from   table_1 t1 inner join prep p on t1.id = p.token
group by p.id;

  ID GROUP_NAMES
---- --------------------
   1 Person1
   2 Person2,Person3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.group_id, listagg(t1.name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1)
  from table2 t2, table1 t1
 where ','||t2.group_id||',' like '%,'||t1.id||',%'
 group by t2.id, t2.group_id
```

Normalize you data model, this perversion !!! Сomma separated list should not exist in database. Only individual rows per data unit.

Comment: This works, unless the order of the names has to match the order of the id's in the comma-separated string.

Comment: how can i add additional fields to this quary from my table 1

Comment: @deskatur Separate `listagg() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1)` per column, or concatenate values in existing `listagg()` like too `listagg(t1.name||'/'||t1.xx,...)`