# Oracle:Multiple comma-separated Variable ID's to Variable Name

Tags: sql, oracle

The tables have the following columns:

Table1:

```
    Client_Name                   | VAR_ID  
Row 1: SchwabM5-Prodtest-Strategy | 3025,2937    
Row 2: SchwabM5-Prodtest-Strategy | 5,7
```

Table2:

```
   Client_Name                    | VAR_ID   
Row 1: A                          | 3025  
Row 2: B                          | 5   
Row 1: C                          | 2937   
Row 2: D                          | 7
```

Question: I want the output as following from the above tables in a single query?

```
Client_Name                       | VAR_ID   
Row 1: SchwabM5-Prodtest-Strategy | A,C       
Row 2: SchwabM5-Prodtest-Strategy | B,D
```

Can you help me in getting the query from which I can get the above output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154561/oracle-join-two-table-with-comma-separated-ids/39154805

Comment: Do not store comma separated values in a column. It leads to pain during data manipulation

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Its an oracle table

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [var_id] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

data in table 1

```
SchwabM5-Prodtest-Strategy | 3025,2937    
SchwabM5-Prodtest-Strategy | 5,7
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [var_id] [int] NULL
)
```

data in table 2

```
A                          | 3025  
B                          | 5   
C                          | 2937   
D                          | 7
```

run the following query

```
WITH [RESULTS]
AS
(
    SELECT  
        [NAME]
       ,CAST ('<Nodes><Node>' + replace([var_id],',','</Node><Node>') + '</Node></Nodes>' AS XML) NODEXML
    FROM [dbo].Table1
)
SELECT [NAME] ,
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + [name] FROM [dbo].Table2 WHERE var_id IN 
                ( 
                    SELECT  tab.col.value('.','int') FROM NODEXML.nodes('//Node') AS tab(col)
                ) FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') CONTENT
FROM RESULTS
```

Comment: How do you know Abhirup Dhar is using SQL Server?

Comment: Its an Oracle table